# How can I remap Capslock on Windows 7 without thirdparty software?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I just upgraded to Windows 7, and I'm trying to reconfigure everything to my liking.  Under Windows XP, I had remapped the Capslock key to behave as a Control key (I spent a long time with Solaris keyboards, and grew to like it).

In XP, I did this as a system-wide setting via the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,3a,00,5d,e0
```

It is my understanding that Vista and 7 have a better way to do this - Something that works on a per-user basis instead of machine-wide.  I recall coming across several pages to that fact when I first looked up how to do it in XP.

However, my google-fu is failing me, and I can't find how to do it.  I've searched this site too, and all I've found is thirdparty software recommendations.  Is there a native way to do this in Windows 7?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[How to remap or disable Caps Lock Key in Windows 7 or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/). Lucky for you, I ran across this yesterday.

From that site, here's the regkey to turn Capslock into a Ctrl key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: +1 I was about to add a link to this - http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-the-Capslock-Key-in-Windows I couldn't find a neater way to do this either...

Comment: I thought vista/7 introduced a better keymapping mechanism, but this works.

Comment: Thanks for a solution. Updating registry solution  worked for Windows 8 Pro x64 too.